# How does bootstrap calculate padding-top element.style for responsive webpage?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar on my bootstrap3.0 website that works almost perfectly. On large screens, the navbar is fixed to the top. On smaller screens, it is still fixed to the top and the menu shrinks to that little "hamburger icon" for drop down menu on a mobile screen.

However, there is a problem I cannot seem to fix. When the website is viewed on a narrow/mobile screen, bootstrap magically adds the following to my page:

```
<html lang="en" style="padding-top: 59px;">
```

I have tried putting setting the html and the body margin to 0 and padding to 0 in my css, the bootstrap css, and even as a style in the index.html page, but this element.style seems to overrides it. I've also searched all my css files, and the 59px magic number appears nowhere, which implies it is calculated on the fly from some variable. I don't know enough about bootstrap or css/less to figure out how/why - which is why i said it is "magically" added :)

Where is it calculating the 59px from, and how can I over-ride this?

Comment: I have been trying to replicate this taking my screen down to 400px but it doesn't show for me. Is Bootstrap the only thing you have added? It is likely to be some js that is injecting the style.

Comment: Good point; let me check my other JS files.

Comment: @bigfish66 - thanks for the hint. found the culprit in a jquery plugin that i installed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you where it's coming from but you can override it with your own style by adding !important to the end of the defintion.  Embedded styles using the style tag will take precedence over other definitions otherwise.

```
.someClass{
   padding-top : 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried that it but it was still over-ridden, which is why I suspected it was done by JS not by css. I'll try to hunt down the culprit in my code. Thanks thought!